# why does moving cookie logic into a function cause unexpected behavior

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, http

so in my express route for login I am using jwt for auth and I want to move the logic into a seperate domain so i slapped it in a function and modified my code. But what i noticed is that when my client side code tries to read the cookie it is not present so the it errors but then after it tries to read the value the cookie appears. I assumed this was a race condition in which the client is reading the cookie before it is set but time of execution between in the route and in a function is trivial. I don't really understand whats going on and I don't want to implement a suspend on the client side to wait for the cookie because of a simple function call.

Before (the working code):

```
const token = jwt.sign(
                { id: userInfo.id, username: userInfo.username },
                process.env.SECRET!,
            );
            let cookieOptions: CookieOptions = {
                httpOnly: false,
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            };
            if (remember) {
                cookieOptions = {
                    ...cookieOptions,
                    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 3600000,
                    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 3600000),
                };
            }
            res.cookie("access_token", token, cookieOptions).json({
                match: match,
                userinfo: {
                    id: userInfo.id,
                    username: userInfo.username,
                    email: userInfo.email,
                    firstName: userInfo.first_name,
                    lastName: userInfo.last_name,
                },
            });
```

After (the problem child):

```
const { token, cookieOptions } = generateAuthToken(
            {
                id: userInfo.id,
                username: userInfo.username,
            },
            remember,
        );
        res.cookie("access_token", token, cookieOptions).json({
            match: match,
            userInfo: {
                id: userInfo.id,
                username: userInfo.username,
                email: userInfo.email,
                firstName: userInfo.first_name,
                lastName: userInfo.last_name,
            },
        }),
```

I see that the functionality hasnt changed and that on refresh of the client the code can read the cookie and the application works as expected. I tried timing the execution of each and saw that there was no meaningful change.

Comment: What's `generateAuthToken`? The client wouldn't see a race condition; the cookie is received when the JSON is. If `generateAuthToken` is async, though, you'd want to wait for it to finish.

Comment: generateAuthToken is just that first code block moved into a separate function. the function does not return a promise.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to help with the information provided--but timing/race conditions aren't it. The client sees nothing until it receives data, and the client app's code isn't doing anything *(roughly)* until its request completes.

Comment: yeah I figured this would require more context that initially provided. The problem is there is so much abstraction in my code that it would be to much to explain and put in a question. Well not much more I can get from here I guess. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from feedback and more research, I have realized that this is more of an issue with the architecture of my application rather than the code implementation. So I will look into alternative solutions.